# Allow text to overflow into adjacent cells (based on size not length)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue that may or not be resolved with the use of VBA (with perhaps a function etc.), but preferably not. I have created a progress bar (see picture below) and was wondering if there is a way to enlarge the number showing the progress (in percentage) without getting the "##" response. In essence, I wonder if there is a way to "allow" the number to be shown in the adjacent cells - opposite to the "Wrap text" function. I'm reluctant to increase the width of my columns due to design reasons with information that are to be placed above the progress bar.

If relevant, there is about 40 columns and the progress (as seen by order of fill from the left) is 0%, 3%, 5%, 8%, 10%, 13%....etc., and the reason for this is to save time and produce something that is "good enough". Each cell have a conditional format deciding wether or not to fill the cell. In additional, each cell have an "IF" formula that determines where the actual progress (in percentage) are to be typed.

Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOv2x.jpg

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is worth putting as an answer, but you could convert it to text e.g. =TEXT(77,"###")

Comment: Edit: @TomSharpe, I thought this was what I needed but my conditional formula "if X is greater than Y..:" doesn't work if it's not a number...:/

Comment: Tom is right, you need to change the cell to text. Then for your condition, use NUMBERVALUE() to get it back as a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK well I'm assuming that your percentage is based on a calculation - say of current date compared to start and finish date. So your actual formula might look like this:

```
=IF(AND(($D3-$D1)/($D2-$D1)>=ROUND((COLUMN()-1)*0.025,2),($D3-$D1)/($D2-$D1)<ROUND((COLUMN())*0.025,2)),TEXT(($D3-$D1)/($D$2-$D$1),"0%"),"")
```

where D1 is start date, D2 is finish date, and D3 is current date.

Your conditional formatting formula would be:

```
=($D3-$D1)/($D2-$D1)>=ROUND((COLUMN()-1)*0.025,2)
```

[image]

Putting in today's date.

I could think of one or two wrinkles like what about 100%? At the moment it would appear to the right of the progress bar- same with 0%, the the first cell gets coloured green before any progress has been made. You could make some adjustments but as you say it's probably good enough.